# Simple ajax function for a basic html site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm a total beginner and I'm trying to build a little project with some friends but I do not know where the problem is. 
The html site is really simple and looks as following:

```
<head>
        <title>The Arena of Champions!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"; href="css/main.css"; type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#start').click(function(){
                $('#main').load('player1.html #main', function() {
                });
                });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to the Arena!</h1>
            <img src="pictures/rock-paper-scissors.gif" alt="rock paper scissors">
            <a><div id="start">START</a>
        </div>
    </body>
```

now what I want the ajax function to do is to just reload my main div and replace it with a second page I have that is called player1.html. That site looks as following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"; href="css/main.css"; type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="form">
            <h1 id="submit-name">Player 1</h1>
            <form action="player2.html" id="playerform">
                <input type="text" name="player1">
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Go!">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Where am I going wrong? I've tried to search here for examples but everyone is using different types of code and it confuses me even more. 
So basically all I want to do is just to update the main div with the contents of the main div in the "player1.html" site.

I appreciate all help!

Comment: `'player1.html #main'` should be `'player1.html'`.

Comment: Even though I just want the #main from player1.html to be used?

Comment: ooh, looks like I get to shove my foot in my mouth, I wasn't aware of the [loading page fragments feature](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the `script tag`
change

```
<head>
        <title>The Arena of Champions!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet"; href="css/main.css"; type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#start').click(function(){
                $('#main').load('player1.html #main', function() {
                });
                });
                });
        </script>
</head>
```

to

```
<head>
  <title>The Arena of Champions!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet"; href="css/main.css"; type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#start').click(function(){
          $( "#main" ).load( "player1.html #main", function() {
              alert( "Load was performed." );
          });
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
```

Note: better put JS before the closing `</body>` for performance reasons

Comment: Thank you for your comment but it still doesnt seem to work. The link "start" is not even "clickable" if you understand what I mean? Nothing is happening

Comment: what is in your console? try to change `$('#start').click(function(){` to `$('#start').on("click",function(){`

Comment: I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when doing as you wrote.

Comment: when I used the previous with the .click(function(){ I got this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Givar/Desktop/Skolarbete/Multimedia/Projektarbete/hemsidan/player1.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You see `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes`

Comment: What does that mean?